# Adding float:left to div makes child link not clickable

Tags: css, hyperlink, css-float, clickable

I know this question was asked at least once before and I have read the other answers. They helped me bypass this problem (there are at least two tricks for this), but what I am asking here is why do I have this problem in my particular setup.

My website is here: [webpage](http://mca.electricmura.ro/?page_id=218)

Scroll towards the bottom and you'll see a div (class "two_third") with tabbed content (it has gray background, you won't miss it). The titles of the three tabs are links (`<a>` elements), but they're no longer clickable. The problem disappears when I remove "float:left" from the div that's immediately to the right (the one with the title "Package content", class "one_third").

What I suspect so far is that "one_third" overlaps with and adds some form of layer over "two-third", thus making links inside "two_third" become unclickable. But this is totally speculation and I have no idea why there would be any overlap, since there's enough space for the two divs to live side by side without any conflicts.

Kindly appreciate your suggestions

Comment: You should use fiddle. I have a same problem but your topic gives me nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a DIV `<div class="horizotal_break clearfix"></div>`. That is on top of the `two_third` DIV. You can't select text from `two_third` either. If you remove `position:relative;` from `#content .horizotal_break` it should be working fine.

Comment: Oh, nice, looks like I was on the wrong track suspecting the other div on the right. I looked at  the page using both Firebug and Firefox's default "Inspect Element" tool, I added solid colored borders around my divs to see if there's any overlap, but none gave me any indication of whom was on top of who. How did you know it was the clearfix div ?

Comment: I use Chrome but in Firebug it is the same, if you hover over a `div` then it will be highlighted on your page. I hovered over all elements near `two_third` and saw that div was in the same place and then I looked at the CSS and spotted the `position:relative;`. You can also fix it by adding `z-index:2;` to `two_third` and `z-index:1;` to `clearfix div`.

Comment: Ah, now I see the problem. I was looking at the clearfix div above the two_third and you were talking about the one below, which I completely missed when inspecting the page myself ! Now I see the overlap. I can either set "position: static", insert a "<b class="clear">&nbsp;</b>" before the overlapping clearfix div or use the z-index approach. But I'm still wondering why the position:relative made that clearfix div extend upwards so much as to overlap my other divs. I hope I'm not abusing your kindness by asking your opinion on this further.

Comment: It is because `two-third` and `one-third`  have a `float`. So if you check the `section` they are in with Firebug you see that the height is only the height of the title and not including the height of `two-third` and `one-third`. Because the `.horizontal_break clearfix` below the `section` has `position:relative;` it will order itself to his previous element which was the `section` with the small height.